# "No viable overloaded =" when compiling the <utility> class

Tags: c++

I'm getting 1 error at compile-time, *"No viable overload '='"*, which points to the following line

```
operator=(pair&& __p) _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_move_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                                 is_nothrow_move_assignable<second_type>::value)
{
    first = _VSTD::forward<first_type>(__p.first); // <------ That line
    second = _VSTD::forward<second_type>(__p.second);
    return *this;
}
```

in the `utility` file. I could probably figure out what the problem is if the compiler showed where in my source files I am effectively using that line of the `utility` file, but it doesn't show. I know it most likely has to do with the following section

```
void ProgramDriver::runInput(const std::string & ipt_str)
{
/*
    iptstr: Input string

    Throws an error if the input string is invalid.

*/
    std::vector<const std::string> substrings;
    std::string this_string;
    for (std::string::const_iterator iter(ipt_str.cbegin()), offend(ipt_str.cend()); iter !=  offend; ++iter)
    {
        char thischar = *iter;
        if (thischar == ' ')
        {
           if (!this_string.empty())
           {
               substrings .push_back(this_string);
               this_string.clear();
           }
        }
        else
        {
            this_string.push_back(thischar);
        }
    }
    if (substrings.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "No input." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<const std::string>::iterator iter(substrings .begin()), offend(substrings .end());
    while (true)
    {
        this_string = *iter;
        if (_programParams.count(this_string) > 0)
        {
            ++iter;
            this_string = *iter;
            if (iter == offend || _programParams.count(this_string) > 0)
            {
                throw "trigger " + this_string + " requires another string after it.";
                return;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else if (this_string == "-r")
        {

        }
        else if (this_string == "-c")
        {
            /* Closes the CSS Genereator Program from the main */
            throw 0;
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
}
```

since that's the one I'm working on everything compiled fine before I made it.

Nevermind ... Found the full error message

```
4:15: In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >::operator=' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:1223:35: In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__value_type<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >::operator=' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/map:941:21: In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::__value_type<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::less<const std::__1::basic_string<char> >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > >::__assign_unique<const std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > *>' requested here
/Users/....: In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::less<const std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > >::operator=' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1330:19: Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>', but method is not marked const
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1333:19: Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>', but method is not marked const
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1337:45: Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>', but method is not marked const
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1338:19: Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>', but method is not marked const
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1341:19: Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>', but method is not marked const
```

Comment: what's the point in `std::vector<const std::string>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what a non-const iterator to a vector of const objects should be able to do. Avoid that pattern. Use const_iterator to avoid modifying the elements.

Comment: @PiotrS. I thought the spirit of C++ was to always declare variables constant if they're not going to be modified after being initialized.

Comment: `const` objects are neither assignable nor movable to/from

Comment: Well it didn't compile even after I changed it to std::vector<std::string>

Comment: well, why don't you trace the entire error message to see which place triggers the error?

Comment: Your code doesn't use any pairs so I have no idea what is causing the error message. Vector may need to modify the string because if it is resized, it may need to move or copy its elements.

Comment: There should be chain of "... instantiated from ..." lines in the error message which ends with the line of your code that is the ultimate cause.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll edit my post.

Comment: too much `const`ness